# Can we edit the "How to Ask" section and add "citizenship!"?

Tags: feature-request

Every visa question should include citizenship (if you want to be persnickety then the passport issuer country) but almost noone does that. Is it possible to add a hint about this somehow?

Comment: It'll be up to the mods, but I'd be in favour of this.

Answer (score 2):

You are suggesting to modify the `Ask a Question` tooltip which appears on the right of a "new question" form. As far as I can see from SO and TSE, that part  doesn't seem to be customisable, aside from changing the `Is your question about xyz` to make `xyz` reflect the nature of the SE site at hand:

[image] [image]

It's the help centre is that is customised by sites on-demand. I don't know if modifying the `Ask a Q` section as you suggest would be a good idea though as it would somewhat become a blazing statement that all we talk about on TSE are visas. Yes you guessed right, `*visa*` questions are in my ignore-list.

I would rather add the information in the help centre. The more informative the help section the better. However don't expect to get very high returns from this as visa-question users rarely read it anyway.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the help section but right on the screen where you add the question.

Comment: Ah. I get it now. I was just checking SO and TSE. The `Ask a Question` section doesn't seem to be customisable, aside from changing the `Is your question about xyz` to make `xyz` reflect the nature of the SE site at hand. It's the help centre is that is customised by sites on-demand. I don't know if modifying the `Ask a Q` section as you suggest would be a good idea though as it would somewhat become a blazing statement that all we talk about are visas.

Comment: As you type the question you get similar questions -- that's where I would add a hint if it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the [visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas) tag wiki, hopefully that will catch a few of them.

Answer (score -2):

### No, we should not do this.

Overusing [citizenship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship) will basically turn it into a meta-tag, and those are not permitted on any Stack Exchange site. Plus, there are other tags with -citizens in them and we will have to add another tag.

Comment: He's not suggesting we add the tag citizenship, just to ask that people include their citizenship in the question...